# Unix command for recursively copying files

Tags: macos, unix, cp

I need a unix command for the following:

Directory Structure

```
/project
    /images
        /products
            /cup.jpg
            /laptop.jpg
        /designs
            /alpha.jpg
            /beta.jpg
            /gamma.jpg
        /team
            /jeff.jpg
        /locations
            /new-york.jpg
```

I would like one command to copy all files* not folders out of the "images" directory recursively to something like this.

```
/assets
    /cup.jpg
    /laptop.jpg
    /alpha.jpg
    /beta.jpg
    /gamma.jpg
    /jeff.jpg
    /new-york.jpg
```

I tried this but it just copied the folders recursively `cp -r ./project/images/* ./assets/`

Comment: I just found this and it works `find project -type f -exec cp {} assets \;`

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. Answering your own questions is not only accepted but [encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/203101). I would recommend, however, that you quote `{}` so you won't have trouble with file names with spaces: `find project/images -type f -exec cp '{}' assets \;`

Comment: @terdon [{} does not have to be quoted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/quoting-curly-braces-in-the-shell).

Answer (score 6):

This executes cp for every file, so it can be noticeably slower if there are many small files (but not with typical images):

```
find project -name \*.jpg -exec cp {} assets \;
```

This takes multiple arguments at a time:

```
find project -name \*.jpg -print0 | xargs -0 -I% cp % assets
```

Without -0 filenames that contain single quotes or double quotes would result in an error like `xargs: unterminated quote`.

[Bash 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55412/cd-to-a-directory-just-by-typing-its-name/55424#55424) supports `**` with `shopt -s globstar`:

```
cp project/**/*.jpg assets
```